# Just rooted and can't enable premium messaging

Tags: root-access, sms, permissions, xiaomi

When I attempt to enable it, it's stuck like in the picture.

[image]

I then receive the message: `Free Msg: Unable to send message - Message Blocking is active.` I've tried other messaging applications, but I can't get it to work. My phone is a Xiaomi Mi Mix 2S.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a root hider or root disguise. That is probably checking to see if you have root access and if so won't compete.